# How to insert a varaible into table using pl/sql bloack?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Requirement** - *Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it; take this value for department id; 'TESTING' is the value for department name and CHN-102 is the value for Location ID.*

*Table name*: **Department**

```
Column name      Data type     Constraints
---------------  ------------  -----------
DEPARTMENT_ID    NUMBER(5)      PRIMARY KEY    
DEPARTMENT_NAME  VARCHAR2(25)   NOT NULL    
LOCATION_ID      VARCHAR2(15)
```

**My code**:

```
DECLARE
    dep number(5);
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX( department_id ) 
      INTO dep
      FROM department  
     WHERE department_name ='TESTING' 
       AND location_id = 'CHN-102' ;
       
    dep:=dep+10;
    INSERT INTO Department ( department_id, department_name, location_id )
    VALUES(dep,'TESTING','CHN-102');
END;
/
```

***Compiler output:***

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("P11743"."DEPARTMENT"."DEPARTMENT_ID")
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're facing means there is no rows in the "department" table with DEPARTMENT_NAME='TESTING' and LOCATION_ID='CHN-102'.

In this case the max() returns null and null + 10 = null which cannot be inserted into department_id column.

After the query is done, you have to check if dep is null or not:

```
...
if dep is not null then
  dep:=dep+10;
  INSERT INTO Department (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,LOCATION_ID)
  VALUES(dep,'TESTING','CHN-102');
end if;
...
```

UPD: I took another look to yout question and I think you're on a wrong way.

Requirement says "Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it"

So, you in order to get this all you need is to

```
Declare
  dep number(5);
Begin
  select nvl(max(DEPARTMENT_ID), 0) into dep
    from Department;
    -- so, no WHERE condition is needed at all. Then do the insert
  dep:=dep+10;
  INSERT INTO Department (DEPARTMENT_ID,DEPARTMENT_NAME,LOCATION_ID)
  VALUES(dep,'TESTING','CHN-102');
end;
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but not complete because even `if dep is null`, it still has to create data as a first record, so you can consider the default value for `dep` and execute the `insert` command in both cases

Comment: Hi @hesamakbari. Thanks, I took another look on the requirements and i'm sure the OP did not get the requirement right.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without plsql in a single statement.

```
insert into department(department_id, department_name, location_id) 
     select coalesce(max(department_id),0) + 10 
          , 'Testing2' 
          , 'CHN-102'
       from department;
```